# Fabricjs: how to stretch NOT proportionally an object?

Tags: fabricjs

[In this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/5KKQ2/279/) I have two arrows; they both share the same path however the orange arrow width is 100 and the red arrow width is 160.

What I'm looking for is to stretch the arrow's line while keeping the size of the arrow head. If I stretch the orange arrow line from 100 to 160, then I get the red arrow, and I don't want this because the arrow head was resized proportionally. I think that the way to do this is having two objects grouped together, but I cannot figure this out. Any ideas?

Javascript:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');


var path = 'm616.422974,216.578644l-150.774078,77.707306l0,-38.516083l-382.556427,0l0,-77.032181l382.556427,0l0,-38.516022l150.774078,76.356979z';

var arrow = new fabric.Path( path, {
    fill: 'orange',
    stroke: 'orange',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    left: 10,
    top: 10
});
arrow.scaleToWidth(100);

var arrow2 = new fabric.Path( path, {
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    left: 10,
    top: 60
});
arrow2.scaleToWidth(160);

canvas.add(arrow, arrow2);
```

Comment: I think that you need to use two objects and group them...

Comment: [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/5KKQ2/282/) I put together an arrow comprised of two objects, the head and the body. I want them to be scaled independently, but moved and rotated as a group. If I group them, I don't know how to resize them independently, and if I ungroup them, I don't know how to rotate them together.